# How to save/discard values of controls of a form, upon pressing Ok/Cancel button?

Tags: c#

Please guide me as how to save/discard values of controls of a form, upon pressing Ok/Cancel button accordingly in Visual Studio C#?

Controls in a form include TablelayoutPanel(TextBoxes), NumericUpDown.

Need your expert guidance

Regards
Asad

Comment: Where do you want to save your data? To a file? Database? Your data model?

Comment: Data is of only few text boxes and 2 numericupdown counter. So i want to save it in System Registry.

Comment: What is the application used for and what is the stored values used for?

Comment: Please see the details below in the answer.

Comment: Some of your comments would be better as an update and clarification of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With both of your buttons, inside the "onclick" event, call a function that will save the content of the form. You also need [this call in the "onclose" event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing%28VS.71%29.aspx) of the form, in case the user presses the top-right X button (or not, if you dont want data to be saved at that moment)

Inside that function, you will need some code that will save data to the registry.

[Writing in the registry is easy](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/sushmita_kumari/registrykeys102082006061720am/registrykeys1.aspx). This webpage also explain how to get the data back. The values you will write will be the textbox.Value and such

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't clear, but in a WinForm you can call

```
this.Close()
```

on the Click event of your Close button.
Every object or variable used by the form will be destroyed. Be careful! running background threads will still be alive until they terminate.

About saving the status of your variables it completely depends on what you need to with them after; you can either keep them in memory and pass them around like parameters or write on a disk (maybe with serialization?).
We need to know more.

*edit*

You may want to take a look at Application Configuration ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658(VS.80).aspx ).

Comment: Yes,its windows form application. Actually the detail is , I have a child form with control menmtioned in question. I want to save /discard values of child form upon pressing Ok/Cancel button from user.

Comment: If user save data by pressing Ok (on child form), then the application will return to main form. Here in main form , I have a button to review/edit/CancelChanges the entered values of child form(as entered previously). So If user want to review the child form values , i just need to restore the same values as entered. If user want to edit the values , form should accept the changes. And if user wants to review it and there it makes some changes in child and then want to cancel these changes, then i need to cancel the CHANGES only not the whole previously stored child form values. Please guide

Comment: Why saving the values to the registry? Do you need to keep them after the application is closed? Do you only need to store one set of values? Isn't it enough to store the values in variables and keep them available for the main form?

Comment: Yes I need to store one set of values at the end.But as mentioned that If user wants to restore the (only one step back ) previoulsy entered values then form need to restore it. So What I assume atleast i need to store two set of values ,one for final storage and one (previously entered) for restoration purpose. And the last stored values will not be required after applicaiton terminates.

Comment: Why not using App.config?  (System.Configuration.Configuration)

Comment: Please give me a slight more detail, as how to use this, as i am listening to this first time!